# Error in na.fail.default: missing values in object - but no missing values

Tags: r, missing-data, error-code, nlme

I am trying to run a lme model with these data:

```
tot_nochc=runif(10,1,15)
cor_partner=factor(c(1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0))
age=runif(10,18,75)
agecu=age^3
day=factor(c(1,2,2,3,3,NA,NA,4,4,4))
dt=as.data.frame(cbind(tot_nochc,cor_partner,agecu,day))
attach(dt)

corpart.lme.1=lme(tot_nochc~cor_partner+agecu+cor_partner *agecu, 
                  random = ~cor_partner+agecu+cor_partner *agecu |day, 
                  na.exclude(day))
```

I get this error code:

> Error in na.fail.default(list(cor_partner = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  : 
>     missing values in object

I am aware there are similar questions in the forum. However, in my case:

- cor_partner has no missing values;
- the whole object is coded as a factor (at least from what the Global Environment shows).

I could exclude those NA values with an na.action, but I'd rather know why the function is reading missing values - to understand exactly what is happening to my data.

Comment: this looks like a typo/thinko to me.  Can you explain what `na.exclude(day)` is supposed to be doing?  I would generally do this by adding `day` to the data frame, then **not** using `attach()`, but instead using the combined data frame-including `day`- in the `data` argument ... ??

Comment: also, in the data set you give there are only 8 values of `day`, and 10 values of all of the other variables, so I get a "variable lengths differ" error ...

Comment: This was an example matrix, they are not the data I am using. day is part of the dt matrix and has 10 values, including NAs, I have edited.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**tl;dr** you have to use `na.exclude()` (or whatever) on the whole data frame at once, so that the remaining observations stay matched up across variables ...

```
set.seed(101)
tot_nochc=runif(10,1,15)
cor_partner=factor(c(1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0))
age=runif(10,18,75)
agecu=age^3
day=factor(c(1,2,2,3,3,NA,NA,4,4,4))
## use data.frame() -- *DON'T* cbind() first
dt=data.frame(tot_nochc,cor_partner,agecu,day)
## DON'T attach(dt) ...
```

Now try:

```
library(nlme)
corpart.lme.1=lme(tot_nochc~cor_partner+agecu+cor_partner *agecu, 
              random = ~cor_partner+agecu+cor_partner *agecu |day, 
              data=dt,
              na.action=na.exclude)
```

We get convergence errors and warnings, but I think that's now because we're using a tiny made-up data set without enough information in it and not because of any inherent problem with the code.

Comment: Thanks, it works without any warning on the actual data. I thought that na.exclude(day) would automatically exclude the whole row based on the value in "day", not work at single column value, so good to know!

Answer (score 16):

`randomForest` package has a `na.roughfix` function that "*imputes Missing Values by median/mode*"

You can use it as follows

```
fit_rf<-randomForest(store~.,
        data=store_train,
        importance=TRUE,
        prOximity=TRUE,
        na.action=na.roughfix)
```

Answer (score 4):

If your data contain NA or missing values you can use this
it will pass the data exactly the same as it is in datasets.

```
rf<-randomForest(target~.,data=train,
                  na.action = na.roughfix)
```

Comment: how does this differ from @kurapati's answer?

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution could be to use `data <- na.omit(train)` which will allow you to pass the data with ease.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).