# Caret gives a missing values error when I use preProcess = "medianImpute"?

Tags: r, na, r-caret, data-science

Having recently completed Datacamp's course "Machine Learning toolbox" I wanted to apply something I learned: caret can input missing values using argument `preProcess = "medianImpute"`

If I run `table(complete.cases(df))` I get:

```
FALSE  TRUE 
24429  6042
```

So I'll need to do something with missing values. The [video](https://campus.datacamp.com/courses/machine-learning-toolbox/preprocessing-your-data?ex=1) made it look so simple!

```
mod.lm.medians <- train(target ~., 
                data = train, 
                trControl = train_control,
                method = "lm",
                preProcess = "medianImpute")
```

Gives:

> Error in na.fail.default(list(target = c(5850000L, 6000000L,
>   5700000L,  :    missing values in object

I found another SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38250440/error-in-na-fail-default-missing-values-in-object-but-no-missing-values) which told me t try `na.action=na.exclude` which lets my model run but only on the complete cases, which is not what I want.

Is my understanding of caret's preprocess parameter incorrect? I expected that missing values would be replaced with the median for the feature for each observation in df. Instead I got this error.

Comment: To investigate you could run the preProcess separately with something like `predict(preProcess(train, method=c("medianImpute")), train)` the reason for the two steps is that the `preProcess `i s learned from the train set but also needs to be applied to the test set. Here we just reapply to train to see the effect

Comment: Hi, I typed that into the console and it runs. I don't follow though! Please ELI5 and use crayons and lego if possible. I.e. I don't know what I just ran. How could I apply this to my model?

Comment: Here is [a pretty good article on caret pre processing](http://machinelearningmastery.com/pre-process-your-dataset-in-r/). It is a little repetitive for each kind of transformation.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I actually stumbled across it while googling for solutions. Will read through. Hoping someone that recognises this caret error sees this too and can comment

Comment: I don't know if you found any solution to this question. I was trying the exact same thing (datacamp) with practicing on a real dataset and got the same error.

Comment: @User2321 it was a while ago now but if my memory serves what I ended up doing was creating a separate training data set before training and cross validation then trained with that. So I applied medians to missing values manually before passing to caret. Not a solution but a work around. If you figure it out please do share

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is with using a formula the preProcess argument. try breaking out the preprocess first and then train...

```
# first preprocess
preproc <- preProcess(train, method = "medianImpute")
trainPreProc<- predict(preproc,train)

mod.lm.medians <- train(target ~., 
                data = train, 
                trControl = train_control,
                method = "lm",
                preProcess = "medianImpute")
```