# random forest- Why do i get an error na.fail.default

Tags: r

```
training_set$left <- factor(training_set$left)
test_set$left <- factor(test_set$left)
```

When I type

```
classifier3 <- randomForest(left~., data = training_set, ntree = 50)
```

I get the error

> Error in na.fail.default(list(left = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  : 
>     missing values in object

Comment: Please edit your question to make it reproducible. A reproducible example consists of sample data, code and expected output. Use `dput(head(df,20))` to add sample data. Provide more context, not just code.

Comment: Also maybe pass `na.action`=`na.omit` in your model call?

Comment: Have you fixed the problem? If yes, what worked?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I can't post this as comment because I don't have enough reputation.
You will find the answer here: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38250440/error-in-na-fail-default-missing-values-in-object-but-no-missing-values). In case of na.fail.default use na.exclude() on the whole data frame at once or an imputation method like `na.roughfix` from `randomForest`.